# iOS get other color than programed

Tags: ios, rgb, uicolor, navigationbar

I want to change the color of the navigation bar.

I declared a variable called "mainColorBlue" and set the navigation bar to mainColorBlue.

```
UIColor *mainColorBlue = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.071 green:0.337 blue:0.533 alpha:1];
```

This is the color **R**18 **G**86 **B**136.

Now, if I launch the app on my device, but the color of the navigation bar is **R**39 **G**97 **B**139 and not **R**18 **G**86 **B**136

What I have to do, that the color is the same?

Comment: `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:mainColorBlue];`

Comment: I found the mistake. It's because the translucent. But if i set the translucent to NO, there are two navigation bars... Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the tint color and the background color are the same. Nav bars can be weird with colors.

Comment: The problem is the translucent, i think